# React renders component even if condition isn't fulfilled

Tags: reactjs, components, render

Can't figure out why React renders a component  for a split second even if condition (preloadedData.length === 0) isn't fulfilled (App.js file, console.log proves it). To make sure - press "start quiz" button after data is loaded, maybe you need to do it several times to see (console.log(preloadedData.length) shows 5).

[image: code]

here is my codeSandBox link:

[CodeSandBox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-bardeen-mxtb9j?file=/src/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

I check your app several times with and without network throtling, but bug isn't appear. Try to debug your app step by step in vscode or other IDE, try to launch build of app without dev and strict mode, maybe its sandbox or chaching/hot-reload bug